# probability of the difference of two random processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

$X_n$ is an i.i.d. random process with marginal exponential distribution:
$$f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \text{ when } x \ge 0$$
where $\lambda > 0$.

I am trying to find $P[X[n]-2X[n-1] < 0]$.

Even though $X_n$ is a random process, can I treat this problem as if I am trying to find the difference between two i.i.d. exponential distributions?
Like:

$$A, B \text{~} Exp(\lambda) \rightarrow \text{Find } P[A-2B < 0]$$

If so, I can figure out the rest.

Comment: Yes, since they are independent.